# Check whether Image has source in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following lines of XAML:

```
<extToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="<image source not set>">
    <Image Source="{Binding FirstSideImage,
                            Converter={StaticResource bitmapConverter}}" />
</extToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

I would like the [`BusyIndicator`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator)'s `IsBusy` property to depend on the availability of the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx)'s [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) property. So if there is no image source, `IsBusy` should be `true`, otherwise `false`.

Is this somehow possible? I could of course have a separate property in my view model that does the same but I'd like to know if I can derive this directly from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a style to the `BusyIndicator`, assuming that the `Image` is the `Content` (i am not familiar with the control):

```
<extToolkit:BusyIndicator>
    <extToolkit:BusyIndicator.Style>
        <Style TargetType="extToolkit:BusyIndicator">
            <Setter Property="IsBusy" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content.Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                        Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsBusy" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </extToolkit:BusyIndicator.Style>
    <Image Source="{Binding FirstSideImage,
            Converter={StaticResource bitmapConverter}}" />
</extToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

You could also directly use the binding in the trigger and apply a converter which turns `null` into `true`.